# Python - DNA Transcription using a for loop

Tags: python, loops

```
dictionary = {1: ['A', 'U'],
          2: ['C', 'G'],
          3: ['G', 'C'],
          4: ['T', 'A']}
def transcribe(S):
"""Converts a single-character c from DNA
       nucleotide to its complementary RNA nucleotide
"""
if S =='':
    return ''
for i in dictionary:
    S = S.replace(dictionary[i][0], dictionary[i][1])
return S
```

Above is my code so far. Below are the tests I am running.

```
print("Function 6 Tests")
print( "transcribe('ACGTTGCA')             should be  'UGCAACGU' :",  transcribe('ACGTTGCA') )
print( "transcribe('ACG TGCA')             should be  'UGCACGU' :",  transcribe('ACG TGCA') )  # Note that the space disappears
print( "transcribe('GATTACA')              should be  'CUAAUGU' :",  transcribe('GATTACA') )
print( "transcribe('cs5')                  should be  ''  :",  transcribe('cs5') ) # Note that other characters disappear
print( "transcribe('')                     should be  '' :",  transcribe('') )   # Empty strings!
```

```
Function 6 Tests
transcribe('ACGTTGCA')             should be  'UGCAACGU' : UCCAACCU
transcribe('ACG TGCA')             should be  'UGCACGU' : UCC ACCU
transcribe('GATTACA')              should be  'CUAAUGU' : CUAAUCU
transcribe('cs5')                  should be  ''  : cs5
transcribe('')                     should be  '' :
```

Above are the results I am getting.

1)I don't understand why C will not convert into G even though I listed it in the dictionary.
2)Is there a way to modify the first if statement so that anything else other than ATCG entered will result in '' being printed?
3) Also, how do I get rid of the space between ACG and TGCA?

Comment: First off, entry 2 in the dictionary changes `C` to `G`, then entry 3 changes the changed `G` back to a `C`. Try using `dictionary = {'A': 'U', ...}` and (with more error-checking, of course) `for ch in S: newCh = dictionary[ch]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> a = a.replace('l', 'x')
>>> a
'hexxo'
>>> a = a.replace('x', 'l')
>>> a
'hello'
>>>
```

You have an entry that converts C to G, but then you have an entry that converts G back to C.

Try having a dictionary that maps a character to the character to replace with:

```
d = {'A': 'U', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}
```

Now you can do something like the following, where you only convert each character *once*.

```
>>> d = {'A': 'U', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}
>>> d
{'A': 'U', 'C': 'G', 'T': 'A', 'G': 'C'}
>>> ''.join(d[ch] for ch in "ACTG")
'UGAC'
>>>
```

This assumes that the string you're working on only contains A, C, G, or T.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's worth considering moving to an intermediate alphabet:

```
from typing import Dict, Final

DNA_2_RNA: Final[Dict[str, str]] = {
    "A": "1",
    "C": "2",
    "G": "3",
    "T": "4"
}

def transcribe(dna: str) -> str: # rna

    temp = ""

    for nucleotide in dna:
        temp += DNA_2_RNA[nucleotide]

    return (
        temp
            .replace("1", "U")
            .replace("2", "G")
            .replace("3", "C")
            .replace("4", "A")
    )
```